# dataframe assign columns from other dataframe with different size by key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = 
key A  B  C  
r1  1  2  7  
r2  6  3  3  

df2 = 
key A  B  C  D  E  
 r1 1  2  3  4  7
 r1 1  3  2  1  5
 r2 5  7  1  2  2
 r2 6  2  4  9  3
 r3 1  2  7  7  1
 r4 9  0  2  1  2
```

I want to add a column E to df1 , so it will take the value from the first occurence of that key from df2.

So df1 will be:

```
df1 = 
 key  A  B  C  E
 r1   1  2  7  7
 r2   6  3  3  2
```

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df1.join(df2.groupby('key')['E'].first(), on='key')
print (df)
  key  A  B  C  E
0  r1  1  2  7  7
1  r2  6  3  3  2
```

Or [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates('key')[['key','E']], on='key', how='left')
print (df)
  key  A  B  C  E
0  r1  1  2  7  7
1  r2  6  3  3  2
```

EDIT:

If possible column `E` not exist modify second solution with [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
print (df2)
  key  A  B  C  D  E1
0  r1  1  2  3  4   7
1  r1  1  3  2  1   5
2  r2  5  7  1  2   2
3  r2  6  2  4  9   3
4  r3  1  2  7  7   1
5  r4  9  0  2  1   2

cols = ['key'] + df2.columns.intersection(['E']).tolist()
print (cols)
['key']

df = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates('key')[cols], on='key', how='left')
print (df)
  key  A  B  C
0  r1  1  2  7
1  r2  6  3  3
```

Comment: Please notice that 'E' is not currently on df , I get the error: KeyError: 'Column not found

Comment: Sorry, I mean that (as in the example), the column 'E' does not exists on df1